# SQL to get Union values if data exists in both the tables based on column

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables (table1 and table2) with common column customer_id, with union and few filters i am getting all the values from table 1 and table2. I need only rows where both the tables have the data based on the common column customer_id. Below is the example.

[image: Source]

The output that I need is as follows

[image: Output]

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT customer_id, 
       age,
       amount,
       type 
FROM table1 
WHERE age > 5 

UNION 

SELECT customer_id,
       age,
       amount,
       type 
FROM table2 
WHERE age > 5
```

Comment: A simple [INNER JOIN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) will do the trick and please never post images , use only text. [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: Do you have the SQL script to re-create those tables? It would be great if you could make a SQL snippet out of it. And you need JOIN first

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: select customer_id,age,amount,type from table1
where age > 5
union
select customer_id,age,amount,type from table2
where age > 5

Answer (score 0):

Your query combines the rows of the two tables but doesn't match customers present in both. What you need to add is the condition on the "*customer_id*" being present in the corresponding other table:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE age > 5 AND customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM table2) 

UNION

SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE age > 5 AND customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM table1)
```

You should choose between:

- `UNION`, if you want to return unique rows between the two tables - makes an additional aggregation operation
- `UNION ALL`, if you want to allow repeated rows between the two tables

If you don't have repeated identical rows in your tables, then you should go with the most efficient one, which is `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Thanks it worked, though i have to add few more filters in "customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM table1 where....and ...)" because the same filters are applied in each of the main select query

Comment: You could also move your conditions inside the subqueries only, like this `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM table2 WHERE age > 5 UNION ...)`